# Geodesics with respect to time-dependent Riemannian Metric

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I'm not sure where to look to solve a problem of this variety.  Does it potentially have to do with Ricci flow?

Suppose we consider Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^n$ and append to it a time-dependent metric of $A(t)$ where $A: \mathbb{R} \to SPD(n)$ is a smooth curve in the manifold of symmetric positive definite matrices $SPD(n)$.  Define the metric on $\mathbb{R}^n$ as $\langle u, v\rangle_t = u^TA(t)v$, in other words a time-dependent metric.  I'm trying to figure out how to find geodesics in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with respect to the same parameter $t$ that the metric is parameterized by.  I know the geodesic equations for an ordinary Riemmanian manfiold are given by

$$
\frac{d^2\gamma^k}{dt^2} + \Gamma_{ij}^k \frac{d\gamma^i}{dt} \frac{d\gamma^j}{dt} \;\; =\;\; 0
$$

with

$$
\Gamma_{ij}^k \;\; =\;\; \frac{1}{2} g^{km} \left ( \frac{\partial g_{im}}{\partial x_j} + \frac{\partial g_{jm}}{\partial x_i} - \frac{\partial g_{ij}}{\partial x_m} \right ).
$$

It's not clear to me how to approach this problem or if it is even well-posed.  Another way I suppose I can phrase this is: how does a curve $\gamma$ naturally "flow" with respect to this metric given the initial conditions $\gamma(0)$ and $\gamma'(0)$?  Can anyone offer any insights or references?  I would appreciate it if I knew a general approach to this problem, or if the problem needs to be posed differently.

Comment: Just a few comments: (1) Your question is how to find the geodesics of the metric $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle_t$, is that it?  Is that what you mean by "geodesics with respect to the same parameter $t$ that the metric is parametrized by"? Or do you mean something else? (2) If there are no conditions on $A(t)$ -- like, if there are no differential equations that $A(t)$ is required to satisfy -- then all sorts of things can happen. Without further conditions on $A(t)$, I'm not sure anything specific can be said; (3) I don't see a direct connection to Ricci flow.

Comment: @JesseMadnick For part (1), yes that's correct.  I'm looking for geodesics of $\langle \cdot,\cdot\rangle_t$.  I understand that many things can happen if there are no constraints on $A(t)$, but my question is more about how to compute the Christoffel symbols if $A(t)$ is independent of the parameters $x_1, \ldots, x_n$.  Can the Christoffel symbols be nonzero?  Also, good to know this doesn't concern Ricci flow.

Comment: I am still struggling to understand your question, since I think Jesse asked you a question and you might have been answering something different. My problem concerns your phrase "find geodesics... with respect to the same parameter $t$". Jesse's question is "Are you just fixing a time $t$ and asking about geodesics on $\mathbb{R}^n$ with this fixed inner product $A(t)$?" If your answer is "yes", then the answer is that all geodesics are straight lines. But I fear that your question may be something different altogether. Your question seems to be asking that at different points along the ...

Comment: ... desired geodesic, you want the metric to correspond to the different values of $A(t)$. If that's the case, it depends on precisely what you mean by the word "geodesic". I can think of at least three different interpretations of what you are asking about in this case, and at least two of them give different answers.

Comment: @WillieWong Using the word "geodesic" may not in fact be a correct usage of the word.  I want to calculate the evolution of a path $\gamma$ as the metric is changing with time with initial conditions $\gamma(0) = p$ and $\gamma'(0) = v$.  In other words, the point $\gamma(t)$ will be subjected to the metric $\langle \cdot, \cdot\rangle_t$.  Does this clarify anything for you?  I'm definitely not interested in the case of a fixed time, but rather seeing how a curve evolves in $\mathbb{R}^n$ while the metric is changing along with it.

Comment: Okay, can you tell me how the metric is expected to influence the evolution of the curve? Is that your question? If you have any ideas, however vague, please at least try to explain what it is.

Comment: @WillieWong Essentially that is my question: does a purely time-dependent metric yield geodesics in $\mathbb{R}^n$ which are not straight lines?  Perhaps my notion of "geodesic" is ill-founded since I've only been exposed to geometry with fixed metrics.  Do you have any suggestions for where I can read up on time-dependent metrics?

Comment: The problem seems a little circular. The parameter t in the geodesic equation is in some sense defined by the geodesic equation and so cannot really be expected to be related in any way to the parameter t of your metric.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer really depends on what you mean by geodesics; you are using a word as if there is a meaning for geodesics of "time dependent metrics" as you described them. There isn't. Below I give three possible interpretations of the notion of geodesics, and associated to them are four possible solution curves, they are all different in general.

### Geodesics are solutions to a certain time-dependent ODE

One way to understand geodesics on a Riemannian manifold is via the [geodesic spray](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spray_(mathematics)), which is in fact defined for any connection, not necessarily one coming from a metric. The idea is that the geodesic equation on a *fixed* Riemannian manifold can be written as a vector field defined on its tangent bundle. Geodesics are then projections of the integral curves of this vector field to the underlying manifold.

In other words, for every fixed time $t$ there exists a vector field $V$ on $\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n$ associated to the metric $A(t)$, and the position/velocity $(p,v)$ of your "time dependent" curve can be taken to mean the naive notion that they solve

$$ \frac{d}{dt} (p,v) = V(t; p,v)$$

As it turns out, however, since the metric $A(t)$ is the constant metric for any fixed $t$, the associated geodesic spray $V(t)$ is always the same: $V(t;p,v) = (v,0)$. This means that the "geodesics" are always straight lines.

### Geodesics are to be interpreted in an overarching manifold

An alternative way to interpret this "time-dependent" geodesic notion is that instead of considering geodesics on the manifold $\mathbb{R}^n$, you consider geodesics of the manifold

$$ \mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}^n $$

equipped with the Riemannian metric $dt^2 + A_{ij}(t) dx^i~dx^j$. You can compute the associated geodesic evolution using the usual way for Riemannian manifolds, by computing the connection coefficients (for example) for the metric mentioned above. In particular you find that the velocities satisfy

$$ \dot{v}^0 - \frac12 \dot{A}_{ij}(t) {v}^i {v}^j = 0 $$

and

$$ \dot{v}^i + \frac12 (A^{-1})^{ij} \dot{A}_{jk} {v}^0 {v}^k = 0 $$

In general solutions to this, after projected to $\mathbb{R}^n$, are not straight lines.

### Geodesics as energy minimizers

An alternative formulation is that we let geodesics be critical points of the energy of length integrals. The energy integral with a "varying metric" is

$$ \int \langle \dot{\gamma}(t),\dot{\gamma}(t)\rangle_t ~\mathrm{d}t$$

while the length integral is

$$ \int \sqrt{\langle \dot{\gamma}(t),\dot{\gamma}(t)\rangle_t} ~\mathrm{d}t $$

The corresponding Euler-Lagrange equation in the energy case is the linear ODE

$$ \ddot{\gamma}(t) + A^{-1}(t) \dot{A}(t) \dot{\gamma}(t) = 0 $$

and in the length case is something slightly more complicated. In general solutions to these equations are also not straight lines, and they are different from the curves defined in the second case above.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer.  I know that my question was somewhat vague, but your two latter approaches (using an overarching manifold, and the Euler-Lagrange equations) were what I was looking for.

Comment: I think the ODE portion of your answer is incomplete. How can the solutions be "straight lines"? The question is how to develop second order ODEs for the coordinates which describe the curve followed where the metric is changing... my guess is it would be the same as for a fixed metric, except where the Christoffel symbols are simply given their time dependence. I think this is what you meant by your answer. That the local curvature is the same as for the fixed metric. But still, we can rewrite the OP's equation with the Christoffel symbols having time dependence, this would be the answer.

Comment: Also are you able to provide references for the energy and length minimisation equations? I am interested in this case too.

Comment: @Myridium: re comment 1: at any instant in time the metric is **constant in space** and hence the they all have the same connection, independent of time. Re comment 2: no. But it is not too hard to compute them yourself.

Comment: @WillieWong - that did not clarify anything for me. I think you meant to say that $$
\frac{d^2\gamma^k}{dt^2} + \Gamma_{ij}^k(t) \frac{d\gamma^i}{dt} \frac{d\gamma^j}{dt} \;\; =\;\; 0
$$ where $$
\Gamma_{ij}^k(t) \;\; =\;\; \frac{1}{2} g^{km}(t) \left ( \frac{\partial g_{im}(t)}{\partial x_j} + \frac{\partial g_{jm}(t)}{\partial x_i} - \frac{\partial g_{ij}(t)}{\partial x_m} \right ).
$$

Comment: @Myridium: and since $g$ is independent of spatial location, your $\Gamma$ are identically zero.

Comment: I guess the OP was asking specifically about spatially invariant metrics.